# Should I request epic cards on sundays if I don't have one to upgrade in my deck?

Tags: clash-royale

In Clash Royale, we are allowed to request 4 epic cards only once a week on sundays. Should I do it considering the following?

- I have no epic cards on my 8 slots deck or similarly, I have epics but they are all maxed.
- I still have rare cards I have to upgrade in main deck so that means it could be interesting to request for rare cards. Please consider the two subcases:

  1. I have rare and common cards that match the appendix of this question.
  2. I only have offensive leveling rare and common cards, see appendix.

#### Appendix: Upgrading strategy- What cards are most important to max?

There's three types of leveling:

- offensive leveling (zap, snowball, trying to win the arms race to get unfair advantage over opponent's cards)
- normal power leveling (giant is relatively level independent, but gets a normal 10% power boost)
- defensive leveling (keeping goblin barrel and musketeer safe from unfair interactions)

The cards in the defensive category are the most fun, and the cards in the offensive category should be done last... with the exception of things like fireball that have defensive AND offensive interactions.

By racing zap up in level, [you harm your fun without realizing it](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale/comments/aqz48x/philosophy_how_people_accidentally_make_the_game/).

---

- **Commons:** gang (to survive zap), tesla (to one-shot minions as
  intended), archers (to survive log), ice spirit (to interact with
  towers and musketeers), fire spirits (to interact with towers)

  - Honorable mentions: minions and horde have to be level 12 to survive
    max zap, so they are important to level, but only to level 12
- **Rares:** musketeers/3M (to survive fireball), furnace (to actually
  exert pressure), rocket (to kill max sparky), zappies (to actually
  kill skeletons), fireball (to avoid bad interactions against pump)

  - Honorable mention: pump needs to be level 12 to prevent losing elixir
    to max fireball, but 12 is sufficient
- **Epics:** goblin barrel (to survive zap), hunter (so pellets one-shot
  skeletons), goblin giant (so the spears kill bats), witch (so she
  one-shots skeletons), poison (to avoid bad interactions against pump,
  and wizards and musketeers), skarmy (so it kills other level 13
  skeletons efficiently)

  - Honorable mentions: barb barrel needs to be level 12 to kill max
    princess, but 12 is fine, balloon needs to be level 12 to survive max
    rocket
- **Legendaries:** eWiz (to survive fireball), royal ghost (to one-shot max
  princess), ice wiz (to survive max fireball), graveyard/night witch
  (need max bats/skeletons to avoid bad interactions with other max
  bats and skeletons)

  - Honorable mentions: log needs to be level 12 to kill princesses, but
    12 is sufficient. lava hound needs to be level 12 so that the pups
    survive zap, but level 12 is sufficient.

[Source: reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale/comments/bb90ip/upgrading_strategy_what_cards_are_most_important/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a definitive answer to this question. The answer is based on your current goals in the game.  That being said, here's my two cents:

**First, some facts:**

If you request epics every Sunday for a year, you will acquire 208 epics that would have otherwise been rare. That's enough cards to level up a single epic from level 12 to 13, 2 epics from 11 to 12, or 4 epics from 10 to 11.

Epic cards are worth 1000 coins on the shop, whereas rares are worth 100. If you wanted to buy 208 rares it would only cost 20,800 coins. Buying 208 epics would cost 208,000 coins.

**So why should you care about leveling up epics that you don't use? The answer is challenges, clan wars, and secondary decks.**

If you want the best chance at winning challenges, you will want every card in your deck to be level 9 so you are never at a level disadvantage.

The same goes for clan wars to an even greater extent. The average card levels in clan wars for bronze, silver, gold, and legendary league, are 9, 10, 11, and 12 respectively. If you want to have the best chance at winning your war day match, you will want to have all of your cards near these levels so you can craft the best deck from the cards you are given.

I have been playing for 2 years, and my clan shifts between high gold and low legendary clan leagues.  My goal is to have every card at level 11. Once every card in my deck is 11 then I start working on leveling something up to 12 until a new card comes out. Then the level 11 grind starts over again.

**If you don't care about challenges or clan wars and you're more concerned with climbing the ladder by power leveling your current deck to level 13, then by all means go ahead and request the rare card to speed things up. After all, it's only 208 cards a year.**

I would still recommend always using the epic request when you can though for the reasons I mentioned above, and also I guarantee you that one day you will get bored with your current deck and will want to switch to something else, or at least have a secondary deck. Rares are cheap compared to epics, so it will be easier/cheaper to play catch up with a second deck if you used all of your epic requests when you could.

For example, once I maxed out the two epics in my main deck, I then started working on Witch on Sundays since I knew I'd like to play around with a giant/witch deck on ladder at some point (I know, how original). As strange as it seems, it helps to make very long term goals in clash because switching directions can take months.

In the case that your epics are all maxed out, then it's not possible to request any epics on Sunday. This is an unlikely scenario however, since you will likely max out commons and rares before you max out epics.